# If I stop a Windows 7 backup part way through, do I keep files backed up so far?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

I am 65% through a Windows 7 backup but my time is running out! If I stop the backup, do I get to keep the files that have been backed up so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If I stop a Windows 7 backup, do I keep files backed up so far?

Short answer: yes.

---

#### How to Stop a Windows Backup in Progress

> When the computer is backing up, it is hard (slow) to do anything else on the computer. If you must use the computer, you can stop the backup. The key to stopping a backup is to find the Stop Backup button.

...

> You’re asked to confirm that you want to stop the backup after you click the Stop Backup button.
>
> - There’s nothing wrong with stopping a backup; it doesn’t destroy any data that’s already on the backup hard drive. Stopping the backup does, however, prevent the backup program from making copies of all the files in need of backing up.
> - You can’t resume a stopped backup, but you can start a new backup when you are done using the computer.

Source [How to Stop a Windows Backup in Progress](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-stop-a-windows-backup-in-progress.html)

Comment: The same effect, I believe, when after hibernate/sleep/shutdown during a backup, the CP offers to restart the backup. It _should_ check the existence, size and time/date stamp on the files already written to backup, which might reduce backup time.